# Python - execution order (file writing and reading)

Tags: python, operating-system, system

Is there any reason why the lines

```
out = open("tmp.gp",'w')
out.write('plot sin(x)')
out.close
system('gnuplot -persist tmp.gp')
```

don't work, but these (below) do?

```
system('gnuplot -persist tmp.gp')
out = open("tmp.gp",'w')
out.write('plot sin(x)')
out.close
```

Note that I do not delete tmp.gp during the program, so in either case the file exists and contains the command 'plot sin(x)' before any of these lines are executed (because the file exists from the previous run)?

My only guess was that this could be a race condition, but putting a raw_input() to kill time didn't help (see below). Thanks for any help!

```
out = open("tmp.gp",'w')
out.write('plot sin(x)')
out.close
raw_input()
system('gnuplot -persist tmp.gp')
```

Comment: Before anything else, are you actually calling `out.close()` or are you really doing `out.close` ? The later does nothing you want.

Comment: Note that relying on the previous run's data seems odd and confusing - it may make sense in context, if so, then that's fine, but otherwise, it's hugely user-unfriendly.

Comment: @mmgp - Great catch. I feel stupid for not seeing that myself.

Comment: @Lattyware - It's a terrible design, yes. I was using it to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are not actually calling the close function, change `out.close` to `out.close()`. Function calls require `()` in order to be called.

Comment: It actually _is_ sort of a race condition, in that he's relying on `out` to be garbage collected before `gnuplot` runs, which is theoretically possible but can fail. (Of course, pretty much always _will_ fail, but that doesn't mean it's not a race, just that it's much easier to debug than most races.)

Comment: As a note, this is another reason why you should use the `with` statement! It makes this kind of error impossible.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned you didnt use close() properly. Also with working on files you should use with statment:

```
with open("tmp.gp",'w') as out:
    out.write('plot sin(x)')
    out.close()
```

this way even if you won't close file yourself or writing to file will raise error, file still will be closed.